# VBA Insert and Link Pictures

Tags: excel, vba, image

What I want to do, is to insert pictures into an excel worksheet. Because there are a lot of pictures, I want to do this using a VBA Sub. These pictures are updated on a regular basis (Graphs that change every time, new data points are obtained). Every Picture should also have a prepared Sub assigned to it.
The current state of the project/Sub is as following:

1. The Pictures are inserted into the excel worksheet using
   `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(path as String)`
2. The prepared Sub `ImageClick` is assigned to each picture by iterating over all Shapes and using
    `ActiveSheet.Shapes(i as Integer).OnAction = "ImageClick"`
3. To keep the pictures up to date, the macro, which builds up the worksheet and inserts all the pictures is called everytime, the workbook is being opened.

This works just fine at this point, but I guess, that this could not be the final solution. With a growing amount of pictures, the runtime might exceed the acceptable values.

My question is, if there is any function or option to automatically **Insert and Link** the pictures (like the option you can choose, when you manually insert pictures into excel), to ensure, that the pictures are always up to date because of the link to the source?

Another question is, whether there might be a problem with assigning the Sub `ImageClick` to these pictures (because of the link)?

Comment: There is a `Link` parameter in the [`PasteSpecial` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Do you also know a way to copy the Picture (.JPG) file to the clipboard, so ```PasteSpecial``` can be used?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a little unspecific. What I mean is, that I have the path to the source file (the pictures). It would be perfect to have the option of saving the file (the Picture.JPG) to the clipboard with only using the path (String).

Comment: Try using the information from [this website](https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/tutorials/vba-copy-to-clipboard-paste-clear/)

Comment: Thank you for the Link, it was quite helpful. Sadly it did not work as I wished. But I found a different solution which worked just fine for my problem by using ```Shapes.AddPicture```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.
By usage of the function [`Shapes.AddPicture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture) you can enable a link to the source file. The parameter `LinkToFile` must be set to `msoTrue` and `SaveWithDocument` must be `msoFalse` to ensure the automatic updating of the pictures (when the workbook is opened again). Because all parameters are necessary, also the exact position of the picture has to be defined.

Assigning macros to the pictures is also possible with [`Shape.OnAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.shape.onaction)`= <Sub_or_Function_Name as String>`.

An example code is provided below:

```
'Sub to insert a linked picture into a Excel Worksheet
Public Sub LoadPicture()
    Dim path As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shc As Shape

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    path = <Filepath as String>

    'All parameter are necessary
    Set shc = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=path, LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoFalse, _
                                Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=100)

    'Assign a prepared Sub or Function to the inserted Shape.
    shc.OnAction = "Click"

End Sub

_________________________________________________________________________________

Private Sub Click()
    MsgBox "You dare to click me?"
End Sub
```